# Amplifier IC - selecting input (Sound Card/Phone jack) and output(Headphones/RCA)

Tags: amplifier, output, input, switching, source

Good evening guys!

I'm trying to figure out the solution to my problem, that I have encountered, but I just can't find anything close.

So, first of all, the situation:

I'm trying to build a 5.1 amplifier.
For that, I'm planning to use 4 amplifier ICs:

- 3 stereo (2 actually stereo, 1 is bridged for center) - TEA2025
- 1 for the subwoofer - TDA2030

I want to be able to switch between input sources:

- Soundcard stereo jacks(1. center/sub, 2. front left/right, 3. rear left/right)
- Phone stereo jack, sending the signal for all ICs

And output devices:

- Headphones(Stereo Jack)
- RCA speakers (6 of them, center, front left, front right, rear left, rear right, subwoofer)

My guess is, to be able to switch input sources, the other source should somehow be denied.
As for the output, the same could be applied.

How can I switch input sources from one audio channel to the next with a circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve tried drawing out what you´re trying to do and it´s given me a headache, so I´ll just point you in the right direction.  :)

For the input, you need a multigang switch [like this one](http://www.jameco.com/1/1/51460-sr2511f-0602-19r0b-e9-s-w-rotary-switch-6-pole-2-position.html). Each pole will go to an input of your 5.1. One position for the soundcard, the other for the phone stereo jack.

For the output, how are you going to drive the headphones? They will need their own (separate) amplifier. Have you thought about that? You could just leave them permanently connected and use a switch box to switch out the main speakers. Something like [this](https://www.amazon.es/Wentronic-12-4-4-way-speaker-switch/dp/B000L0X6H8?ie=UTF8&creative=24538&creativeASIN=B000L0X6H8&hvdev=c&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=&linkCode=df0&ref_=asc_df_B000L0X6H832916215&tag=googshopes-21).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. When the jacks are connected, the socket separates the left and right channels. How do i connect those to a switch like that? Also, the jacks are connected to the sockets, then I connect them to that switch, then on the output of the switch there will be only 1 channel. (I think i get this wrong for some reason though..

Comment: Yes, that´s why you need a 6-pole switch. Two sets of L and R, Center and Sub. So each channel on the amplifiers connects to a pole on the switch and then you choose one of the 2 inputs.

Comment: I guess I'll have to read a bit about poles and throws, thanks for clearing it up :)